# Invalid prospect email address at Pardot Salesfoce

Tags: salesforce, email-formats

I am trying to create a prospect at Pardot- Salesforce from the python API with this format :

> {'brand': 'brand1', 'platform': 'Platform 1', 'email': 'testexample+tn39@gmail.com', 'first_name': 'Test', 'last_name': 'User39', 'addr_country': 'United Kingdom', 'opt_in': True}

I am getting this [error](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/error-codes-messages/#error-code-4) :

> Invalid prospect email address

This is obviously because of the email's format , but according to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pardot_emails_allowed_characters.htm) official article that the character **"+"** is an allowed character for the email field.

So any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: I have the same problem, but with an email address that has a dot: "glory.w@gmail.com"... 
Does your email address exist? I read that Pardot considers as invalid emails that don't exist. But mine exists... :/

Answer (score 0):

I was spending a lot of time on this as well but you will need to encode the + symbol to the html encoding`%2B` for it to work... super annoying that it is not in the documentation...
For encoding you can use the website below
https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can encode the whole email portion and send it to the API call.. Pardot on its backend did the decode for the special characters and saving to its original email state

for example:
`Urlencode(test.12+{}!~3@gmail.com)` and pass it to the API-> it works..
sample API call after encoding the email  `/4/do/create/email/test.12%21%23%24%25%26%27*%2F%3D%3F%5E_%2B-%60%7B%7C%7D%7E3%40gmail.com?format=json`